# No distribute, only for self modifications license

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

I am programming three things, an API, an Android app, and a front-end web React app.
The whole system will be sold to a company for money, I have no problem with them modifying the source code to fit their needs and making my system communicate with their APIs, but I don't want them to copy my system and give it to other companies.

I want this license to only allow them to do whatever they want with my source code only for their own uses, but not for selling it or sharing it with others.

Which license I should use?

Comment: they shouldn't be allowed to share the original source code or the modified source code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the requested license is not in any way an open source license and is therefore off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a proprietary license, what you are asking is not possible with an open source license. You might want to contact a lawyer to draft a license (without sublicensing rights) for you.

Depending on the upstream libraries (and their licenses) which you use in your apps and API, a proprietary license may not be possible. If you use libraries which have a copy-left license you likely have to license your own software under the same license. If, however, the libraries you are using are under a permissive of PD license, then you can go the way described in the 1st paragraph of this answer.